# Carcassonne: Replacement/Extra player sets.

Tags: carcassonne, components

So far I've found [MeeplePeople](http://www.meeplepeople.com/products.php?cat=44) and [BoardGameExtras](http://www.boardgameextras.co.uk/index.php?sub_category=Extra+Player+Sets&category=Carcassonne&sub_cat=1&cat=1) carrying replacement/extra sets for Carcassonne. I am however missing Mayor, Farm and the Cart(?) from those sets (possibly some expansion I have not played has other tokens as well).

Does anyone know where I can get extra/replacement parts for the full range?

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question; if your answer is the best one, it can be upvoted and accepted just like any other. It will also bump the question, and someone else might notice it and provide a better answer.

Comment: Yes I know I can accept my own it just wasn't even the correct pieces for myself as I'm a bit mental about it not looking right. Though I'm doing it to get a pink set for the GF not for replacement so I have time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did find possible Farm & Cart replacement on [BoardGameBits](http://boardgamebits.com/store/index.php?main_page=index&cPath=1_44) not the correct ones but if it is for replacement it might help someone.